# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory for package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, file-not-found, laravel-10

I'm helping a friend update their package to support Laravel 10 (and I'm learning Laravel along the way) and I keep getting `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` when Sail starts.
It's trying to load the service provider file for 'our' package, but the error reads that it cannot find the file in question.

The file (GravityServiceProvider.php) is in the folder that Sail is complaining about (/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../bubalubs/gravity/src/).

I've tried deleting the composer.lock file, deleting the vendor folder and running `composer install` and can see the package installs without errors. The package even completes any migrations needed. I tried clearing any compose cache. I tried running composer update after clearing cache, still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish your provider. Follow this instructions found here if it's correct package https://github.com/Bubalubs/gravity

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention I'd gone through the installation steps.

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public` publishes the resources to `/public/vendor/gravity` which works.
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Bubalubs\Gravity\GravityServiceProvider` gives me the message of "No publishable resources for tag []"

Still get the error of file/directory not found after trying those commands again

Comment: Something I don't understand is the above command (`php artisan vendor:publish...`) runs fine and will publish the assets, but that information is inside the file GravityServiceProvider.php - so that means the file itself is in place and readable?

Comment: Tried clearing all kinds of cache's and now get `There is no existing directory at ".../storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied`
Tried changing chmod to 755, 775, and 777, none of which rid the error.

Comment: Trashed the site in case I'd messed something up, and started again. Still get the same "No such file or directory" error

Comment: I've used `file_exists()` in `ClassLoader.php` to check the file does exist, and that passes. Then tried `is_readable()` and that fails. I've checked the permissions trying 755, 775, and 777 - none make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's so glaringly obvious now after trying the `file_exists()` and `is_readable()` whilst using Sail. A small detail I left out was the package was in a folder outside of the project. So yes, PHP could 'see' the file hence it passed the `file_exists()` check, but Sail couldn't read it as it was outside of the container.

I've moved the package into a `packages` folder inside of the project, and referenced that instead. Getting different errors now, but they seem to relate to the actual codebase of the package and not file/permission related.